# How to get tables to appear in the top section instead of a list of tables?

Tags: tables, ieeetran, rstudio

I'm writing a paper in IEEEtran format using *RStudio* and *rticles* ([ieee_article](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/rticles/man/ieee_article.html) format).

When I insert the first table in the document via a new block LaTeX (MarkDown tables do not get converted to tables using this rticle format), such as:

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

a "List of tables" section appears at the end of the final document with the table in another page after it. I just want the table to be placed at the top of the page as the following the IEEEtrans format specification, but I cannot manage to get it to work.

I have tried with `\begin{table}[!t]`, `\begin{table}[t]` and `\begin{table}[]` and all produce the same result: a new list of contents and the table in a separate page.

Example of current output:

- New page with "List of tables":
  [image]
- One more page containing only the table:

[image: Table]

Comment: ieeetran format does not have a ToC

Comment: Please make a real compilable example and clarify your question.

Comment: @percusse I know. The problem is that it generates a "List of tables" not a "Table of contents" (ToC)

Comment: my bad I meant LoT but typed ToC

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.